# latitude longitude into corresponding location in a image

Tags: latitude-longitude, photogrammetry

I have an image , some data on this image, some data on the camera that took that image and a piece of code.
And i'm trying to find the location (Px,Py) in the image from (lat,lon).

**my problem is that i don't know what is R0 , A1 , A2 from the camera data. how many values they have?**

**How do i calculate the radial dist. of A1 and A2?**

**And how do i calculate the distortion of R0?**

(i got the camera data the way i posted it below.. messy)

I did mange to get x , y from collinearity equations using image rotation matrix, focallength... (after converting the data to ecef)
(lat,lon,alt) = (48.13564, 11.58147, 507)    // altitude from DEM

after calculation:    x = 0.0061  , y = 0.0523

Now i got this code that suppose to find the location (Px,Py) in the image using that (x, y) that i found:

```
    // x and y from collinearity equations using image rotation matrix, focallength …




 //orientation x in –row direction
    //orientation y in –col direction

    r = sqrt(x*x+y*y) ;
    dr = interior->radialdist_A1*(r*r-interior->distortion_R0*interior->distortion_R0)
                 + interior->radialdist_A2*(r*r*r*r-interior->distortion_R0*interior->distortion_R0*interior->distortion_R0*interior->distortion_R0) ;
    dx = dr*x + interior->xPrincipalPoint;
    dy = dr*y + interior->yPrincipalPoint;

    *x_out = (x + dx ) ;
    *y_out = (y + dy ) ;

    Row = -x/pixelsize + centerrow
    Col = -y/pixelsize + centercol
```

**

- image data:

**

opk   3.99086  -2.62820 -68.23817

rpy  -1.28306   4.37035 110.28155

XYZ 692053.711 5334599.154  1612.905 (in utm zone 32)

LONLAT  11.58147  48.13564

Ground To Image Rotation Matrix

0.37035919   -0.92766421   -0.04767790

0.92775612    0.36688624    0.06828668

-0.04585474   -0.06952406    0.99652584

**

- Camera data:

**

Col row  pixelsize                image center              R0            principal point xp, yp             A1                        A2                                                                                                                                                                               focallength

3744 5616  6.410000e-06  1872.000  2808.000   0.01400 6.793401e-07 2.887295e-05 -2.276840e+01 1.239733e+04 1.489102e+05 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 5.168871e-02

Answer (score 1):

So i found the answer and i decided to shere it.

Apparently **R0 , A1 , A2** has only one value and they are the 
radialdist_A1 , radialdist_A2 and distortion_R0 in the code.

I also discovered that i needed only to convert the (lat,lon) to utm zone 32.

And then everthing works!